# How to maximize browser window using WatiN?

Tags: c#, watin, maximize-window

I'm trying to maximize the browser window opened by [WatiN](http://watin.org/):

```
var browser = new IE();
browser.SizeWindow(width, height);
```

but I don't know how to set **width** and **height** to my screen size.

Comment: Usually you should look for something like `WindowStyle` if you actually want to maximise the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
```